# ¿Como puedo hacer que devuelva todos los usuarios de un row y no solo uno?

Tags: php, mysql, php5

¿Como puedo hacer que muestre todos los nombres de usuario y la cantidad que llevan? hasta ahora solo me devuelve el primer usuario y los demas no...

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);


$ayer = new DateTime(''.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day')).'');
$ayer = $ayer->getTimestamp();

$hoy = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$hoy = $hoy->getTimestamp();

$link = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', '12345678');
foreach ($link->query('SELECT * from members') as $row) { 
    $id_de_usuario= "". $row['id']. "\n";
    $username= ''. $row['username']. "\n";

foreach ($link->query("SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM ptsu_requests WHERE     status='Completed' AND date>=$ayer AND date<=$hoy AND user_id=" .     $id_de_usuario) as $row) { 

$fila1 = '' . $row['total'] . "</br>";

echo $fila1;


function setRankings($standings) {
    $rankings = array();
    arsort($standings);
    $rank = 1;
    $tie_rank = 0;
    $prev_score = -1;

    foreach ($standings as $name => $score) {
        if ($score != $prev_score) {  //this score is not a tie
                $count = 0;
            $prev_score = $score;
            $rankings[$name] = array('score' => $score, 'rank' => $rank);
        } else { //this score is a tie
            $prev_score = $score;
            if ($count++ == 0) {
            $tie_rank = $rank - 1;
        }
        $rankings[$name] = array('score' => $score, 'rank' => $tie_rank);
    }
    $rank++;
}
return $rankings;
}

//===================================================
//test the above function

$scores = array(
    $username => $fila1
);
$rankedScores = setRankings($scores);

//display the player rankings
foreach ($rankedScores as $player => $data) {
    echo $player . ' - ' . $data['score'] . ' - ' . $data['rank'] . '<br     />';
}
}
}



?>
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu lógica. ¿Por qué tienes dos consultas y además por qué ese extraño ... `('SELECT * from members') as $row` intuyo que algo no anda bien en esa forma de escribir tu código.

Comment: La primera consulta me da los nombres de usuario y los id de usuario. La segunda consulta toma los datos de otra tabla sumando todas las columnas de la tabla ptsu_requests con la condición de que el status sea completado y el user id sea el mismo. Es la razón por la cual hago dos consultas, en todo caso el problema es que cuando se ejecuta la función solo toma el primer nombre de usuario y no los demás. Si elimino la función del código y nuestro en un echo los rows, se muestran todos los usuarios con sus respectivas sumas.

Comment: La consulta que hace el `COUNT(*)` no parece relacionarse con ninguna columna de la 1ª consulta. Me parece que puedes obtener todo en una sola consulta, relacionando las tablas.

Comment: Me refiero a que puedes enviar una sola consulta así: `SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM members m INNER JOIN ptsu_requests r ON m.user_id=r.user_id WHERE r.status='Completed' AND r.date>=$ayer AND r.date<=$hoy GROUP BY m.user_id` ... luego, en cuanto a la lectura de los datos, debes usar uno de los métodos `fetch` dentro de un `while` para ir moviendo el conjunto de resultados y mostrando los datos. Dado que el código está bastante confuso, en parte a esa forma extraña de anidar consultas innecesariamente, no llego  a escribir una respuesta. Al menos prueba mi consulta y verifica si arroja los datos

Comment: Tampoco entiendo realmente por qué usas tus consultas dentro de bucles `for` todo el rato. Muchas partes de tu código hacen intuir que no estás aplicando buenas prácticas de programación, lo digo sencillamente como una crítica constructiva, puede que me equivoque, pues no conozco del todo tu contexto, pero cuando veo demasiadas consultas dentro de bucles me da mala espina. Supongamos un bucle de miles o millones de iteracciones, ¡o infinito! en el que se envían dos o más consultas (quizá de forma innecesaria)... el servidor o la BD podrían terminar exhaustos.

Answer (score 0):

Debes sacar la declaración de la función `setRankings()` fuera del bucle, de lo contrario te dará error de **Fatal error: Cannot redeclare setRankings() (previously declared in...**

Desconozco porque no se muestra o porque no lo comentas, pero dará error seguro.

Ademá, no deberías usar la misma variable `$row` en dos bucles anidados, aunque actúen en ámbitos diferentes te pueden fallar o dar lugar a confusión.

Y en general, deberías hacer caso a A. Cedano y replantearte la forma de estructurar el código.

Prueba:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function setRankings($standings) {
    $rankings = array();
    arsort($standings);
    $rank = 1;
    $tie_rank = 0;
    $prev_score = -1;

    foreach ($standings as $name => $score) {
        if ($score != $prev_score) {  //this score is not a tie
            $count = 0;
            $prev_score = $score;
            $rankings[$name] = array('score' => $score, 'rank' => $rank);
        } else { //this score is a tie
            $prev_score = $score;
            if ($count++ == 0) {
                $tie_rank = $rank - 1;
            }
            $rankings[$name] = array('score' => $score, 'rank' => $tie_rank);
        }
        $rank++;
    }
    return $rankings;
}

$ayer = new DateTime('' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day')) . '');
$ayer = $ayer->getTimestamp();

$hoy = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$hoy = $hoy->getTimestamp();

$link = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', '12345678');

foreach ($link->query('SELECT * from members') as $row) {
    $id_de_usuario = "" . $row['id'] . "\n";
    $username = '' . $row['username'] . "\n";

    foreach ($link->query("SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM ptsu_requests WHERE     status='Completed' AND date>=$ayer AND date<=$hoy AND user_id=" . $id_de_usuario) as $row) {

        $fila1 = '' . $row['total'] . "</br>";

        echo $fila1;


//===================================================
//test the above function

        $scores = array(
            $username => $fila1
        );
        $rankedScores = setRankings($scores);

//display the player rankings
        foreach ($rankedScores as $player => $data) {
            echo $player . ' - ' . $data['score'] . ' - ' . $data['rank'] . '<br     />';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ahora si me devulve todos los resultados, pero me dice que todos son la posicion 1, no esta contando... si escribo el array manualmente ejemplo `$scores = array(
           "usuario1" => 50,
           "usuario2" => 20,
           "usuario3" => 100
        );`

en ese caso si funciona correctamente el ranking, el problema creo es con las variables en el array

Comment: Será por la línea: `$fila1 = '' . $row['total'] . "</br>";`,  déjalo solo con `$fila1 = $row['total'];`  para que haga bien el calculo.... avisa y edito si es correcto esto.